# Show/Hide textboxes- Visible

Tags: c#

I am currently working with visible attributes on textboxes. Below I copy/pasted a snippet of my code. I have a total of 8 textboxes set to visible false as the form is loaded. Then I have two radio buttons that display the textboxes accordingly. One `radioButton` will display the first 4 textboxes and the other will display all 8 textboxes. The problem is when switching back to `radioButton1` to only show 4 textboxes it will still display all 8 textboxes?

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = 0;
        int txtBoxVisible = 3;

        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (count <= txtBoxVisible)
            {
                TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null) textBox.Visible = true; 
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = 0;
        int txtBoxVisible = 7;

        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (count <= txtBoxVisible)
            {
                TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null) textBox.Visible = true; 
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null && rb.Checked)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int txtBoxVisible = 3;
        HideAllTextBox();
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {

            if(count > txtBoxVisible) break;

            TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;

            if (count <= txtBoxVisible && textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.Visible = true; 
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null && rb.Checked)
    {

        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null) textBox.Visible = true; 
        }
    }
}

private void HideAllTextBox()
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null) textBox.Visible = false; 
    }
}
```

In any case, it would be better to iterate through the controls or similar name, for greater accuracy of the affected controls

Comment: when i go back to only show 4 textBoxes, it still displays 8?

Comment: Updated! Added HideAllTextBox method

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckedChanged` event occures when the `Checked` property of the `RadioButton` control has changed. This means both when the `RadioButton` is checked or unchecked.

Try writing something similar to:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        // Display the first 4 TextBox controls code.
    }
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        // Display all TextBox controls code.
    }
}
```